# Flex fill remaining space in React

Tags: html, css, reactjs, flexbox

I have a contact page component that does not fill the viewport, so I need to flex-grow the content section to keep the footer at the bottom. Unfortunately [this vanilla solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/90178/make-a-div-fill-the-height-of-the-remaining-screen-space?rq=1) didn't work in my React project. I adapted it to what I thought would work:

App.js:

```
import ...

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="app-container">
      <NavigationBar className="nav-container"/>
      <Router className="content-container">
          <Route exact path="/" component={HomePage} />
          <Route exact path="/home" component={HomePage} />
          <Route path="/classes" component={GroupClasses} />
          <Route exact path="/lessons" component={PrivateLessons} />
          <Route exact path="/contact" component={Contact} />
      </Router>
      <Footer className="footer-container"/>
    </div>
 );
}
```

App.css

```
html,
body,
#root{
  height:100%;
  margin: 0
}

.app-container{
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  height: 100%;
}

.nav-container{
  flex: 0 1 auto;
}
.content-container{
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}
.footer-container{
  flex: 0 1 auto;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure router takes a prop of className? Can you inspect the element and make sure "content-container" is an active class in the document? Reproducing with a minimal example in a react fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/boilerplate/react-jsx may help

Comment: In most/all cases, using `100%` for an element height does not cause it to fill all the available vertical space instead. If you don't have elements above or below `.app-container`, you could try `height: 100vh` which _does_ take the full height.

Comment: `flex-flow: column;` shouldn't that be `flex-direction: column;` ? [**The rest looks fine**](https://jsfiddle.net/4dqbyzso/)

Comment: Use `position: fixed` for the footer or make a margin bottom fo the page so you can see the footer. can you upload the code?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be working just fine as you can see with [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p7f3bcm6/1/)

I believe the issue you are having is that you can't give a `Router` a `className` as it is not an actual element on the page. Therefore your `content-container` class needs to be applied to the individual component wrappers within the component itself.